# Basic benchmark for oltp databases

Tags: sql, benchmarking, rdbms

Im looking for benchmarks that tested different RDBMS running on the same enviroment to use as reference for a project. Im not looking for any test in particular just want a source of comparison for a few RDBMS something like [Techempowers benchmarks](https://www.techempower.com/benchmarks/#section=data-r12&hw=peak&test=json) for development frameworks. Does anyone know where I can find this? It would be really helpful for me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: From the [help/on-topic]: *Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**TPC-C** at http://www.tpc.org,  is a Benchmarks used to simulates a complete computing environment where a multi-users executes transactions against a database.

The benchmark is centered around the transactions of an order-entry environment.

These transactions include entering and delivering orders, recording payments, checking the status of orders, and monitoring the level of stock at the warehouses.

TPC-C involves a mix of five concurrent transactions of different types and complexity either executed on-line or queued for deferred execution.

The simultaneous execution of multiple transaction types that span a breadth of complexity

- On-line and deferred transaction execution modes
- Significant disk input/output
  -Transaction integrity (ACID properties)
- Non-uniform distribution of data access through primary and secondary keys
- Databases consisting of many tables with a wide variety of sizes, attributes, and relationships Contention on data access and update

It's used for selecting best hardware /database/Price Performance

you can find TPC-c for many database engines runing in different environment at:

[The TPC defines transaction processing and database benchmarks and delivers trusted results to the industr](http://www.tpc.org/tpcc/results/tpcc_results.asp?print=false&orderby=tpm&sortby=desc)

You can sort / concentrate in environment you need.

Concentrate on two numbers in table (based on database and hardware/o.s)

**(tpmC)**  : absolute number , as increase as best performance

**Price/tpmC** : relative cost per dollar (just relative)